# How do I change the page name for the root frame navigation in a Windows 10 UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, azure-application-insights

I have an `App.xaml` file that sets the root visual to be a `Frame` and then immediately navigates to a page called `Shell.xaml`. Inside `Shell.xaml` I have implemented a hamburger menu and have another `Frame` control where the main application's navigation is taking place.

I am using Application Insights to track telemetry within the application. I wired up the `Navigated` event on the `Frame` nested within `Shell.xaml` and add a `TrackPageView` event within there to track all page navigations in one place. This is really nice because I don't have to do it in the `OnNavigatedTo` override in every single page.

Here is the implementation of that `OnNavigatedToPage` event:

```
private void OnNavigatedToPage(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var pageName = e.Content.GetType().Name;
    ViewModelDispatcher.Telemetry.TrackPageView(pageName);

    // After a successful navigation set keyboard focus to the loaded page
    if (e.Content is Page && e.Content != null)
    {
        var control = (Page)e.Content;
        control.Loaded += Page_Loaded;
    }
}
```

The problem is this works for every page **except** for the initial navigation to the `Shell.xaml`.

When I look at Application Insights I get a nice list of pages that have been browsed to:

- AwesomeView
- AnotherCoolView
- MyView
- **application:MyRootNamespacePrefix.Shell**

Call me OCD but my elegant implementation in the nested shell produces very nice and clean page names that correspond to just the class name of the XAML view. I omit all the nasty namespace prefix. However, the navigation to Shell does not.

It should be noted that I am not calling the `TrackPageView` anywhere else in the application so I am assuming that somehow the Application Insights framework code is picking it up auto-magically.

How do I change it so that my Shell doesn't have the nasty `application:MyRootNamespacePrefix.` in front of the actual class name?

**UPDATE:** 
Eureka! It looks like I was right. The Application Insights Framework must be adding a hook to the root visual's Navigated event if it happens to be a Frame. All I did was add the same handler to the root frame that I added to the nested frame and it started showing up as "Shell". Unfortunately, application insights appears to add its own handler for the `Navigated` event of the root visual so while I get my nice clean PageView for "Shell" I also get the one with the nasty prefix.

Comment: Did your **UPDATE** solve the question? Or is there still something you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing your own page view telemetry, you probably want to remove the initializer that collects them automatically:

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-get-started/

you probably have something like this:

```
WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync();
```

but what you want is probably the explicit one, like:

```
WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync( 
    yourIKey, // not sure if you can leave this null to get the key from config file?
    WindowsCollectors.Metadata
    | WindowsCollectors.PageView // remove this one?
    | WindowsCollectors.Session
    | WindowsCollectors.UnhandledException);
```

and take out the pageview auto collector?